# Flash.text.textfield.ScrollV no more works with newest flash player 10.1

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

Scrolling textfield is no more working with player 10.1.82

My code is: SCROLLV = SCROLLV +2

text is scrolling down nicely with older players, but now with newest player it never scrolls.

scrolling WORKS OK with player: 10,0,12,36

scrolling  FAILS with player: 10,1,82,76

Comment: Maybe this is more appropriate for the Adobe bug base?

Comment: Did you check your scrollpolicy?

Comment: well, I am looking for a workaround. What is scroll policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across this too.

The problem is that the scrollV property of my textfield is reset to 1 when I add new text, instead of retaining it's previous value.

I can run two identical swfs in old and new flash players and I see one keeps it's scrollV and the other resets to 1.

The workaround is to store the scrollV value in a variable before you add new text, then set the scrollV back to that value afterwards.

I am using htmlText BTW, not sure if this is relevant.